# Attempting to Instantiate an object using C# and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am new to coding and I am using a book called "Learning C# by Developing Games in Unity 2019 - Fourth Edition.  In one of the exercises it asks to instantiate an object who's class is declared on a different .cs file, when I attempt to instantiate however it doesn't work.   I thought it would be because of a using statement but its not that either.  Here is my code.

```
//LearningCurve.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LearningCurve : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Character hero = new Character();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}

//Character.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Character 
{

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? In your code, `hero` is local variable in `Start()` function, and the function is called just before the first `Update()` call, as discribed.

Comment: what I mean is that when I type in "Character"  and name the variable "hero" and assigned it "=' to "new Character();"  I was under the impression that if I hovered over "hero" it would show me that "hero" is indeed a variable of type "Character" but instead it show "? hero"

Answer (score 0):

Your `Character` instance would be definitely created, but It seems there is no way to confirm it in your code. Unity `Monobehaviour` script starts working when it is attatched to actual gameobject as Component. Try this start function:

```
void Start()
{
    Character hero = new Character();
    if (hero != null) Debug.Log("Hello, Hero");
}
```

This means that if your `Character` instance is well created, then It will log "Hello, Hero" in Unity console.

Then attach `LearningCurve.cs` to any existing gameobject in scene (for example, camera), then start the game, closely looking console.

Comment: So from what I can tell,  it ussually turns a certain color when I create it in this case it doesnt.   I will take a look at that a little later but thanks for the help

Comment: Ok so I have updated the Character Class to inherit from MonoBehaviour, with that added it allows for your code to work, my question though is, I keep seeing "Character" show up in the same color as a variable instead of changing,  it at least now shows as a "Character" type when I hover over it but when i do the new key work and make a "new Character"  i get a big red circle with an x inside of it.  any idea what that could be?